# How to write SQLite file via Room in external storage, by using upcoming Scoped storage?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-external-storage

One of our app requirements is that some SQLite file should be retained and backup, even the app is uninstalled.

We achieve such, by writing SQLite file via Room, into location `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory`

### RoomDatabase with customizable SQLite file path

```
@Database(
    entities = {Backup.class},
    version = 1
)
public abstract class LocalBackupNamedRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract BackupDao backupDao();

    public static LocalBackupNamedRoomDatabase newInstance(String dbName) {
        LocalBackupNamedRoomDatabase INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                WeNoteApplication.instance(),
                LocalBackupNamedRoomDatabase.class,
                dbName
        )
                .build();

        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

### Function returns Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory

```
public static String getBackupDirectory() {
    if (backupDirectory == null) {
        File _externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (_externalStorageDirectory == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            backupDirectory = _externalStorageDirectory.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }

        if (backupDirectory == null) {
            return null;
        }

        backupDirectory = toEndWithFileSeperator(backupDirectory) + "com.yocto.wenote" + File.separator + "backup" + File.separator;
    }

    return backupDirectory;
}
```

### How we save SQLite file via Room in external storage

```
LocalBackupNamedRoomDatabase.newInstance(
    getBackupDirectory() + "local-backup"
).backupDao().insert(backup)
```

According to [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/android-q-scoped-storage-best-practices.html), my understanding is that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` might not be usable anymore (am I correct??).

My guess is that, in order to achieve the same behavior, I might need to use `MediaStore.Downloads`? But how?

Can anyone provide a concrete example for the above use case? Or, we are no longer possible to achieve such behavior, under Scoped storage?

Answer (score 1):

From my own experiments with the Q beta 2 emulator, with a test app with `targetSdkVersion 'Q'`:

Initially `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).exists()` was false, which led me to believe you can't even access it in Q. Then I found `mkdirs()` worked, and I could then read and write to a sandboxed view of this folder restricted to my app's files only. This has the interesting side effect that multiple apps can write files with the same name to the 'download' folder, and that's how they show in the default files app on the emulator!

As the docs mention, you lose access to your own files after uninstall then reinstall. So, in order to restore a sqlite file from downloads after uninstall, you'd have to:

- "allow the user to choose a file using the system's file picker app." (from docs)
- This will give you a URI rather than a File. Because `SQLiteDatabase` can only read `File`s, you'll need to open the URI as a stream and write it to a real file somewhere you control, eg cache or internal storage.

This is a pain, but doable for most use cases. It gets tricky for very large database files, eg mapbox tiles which may be hundreds of mb or more, stored on an actual SD card because they won't fit on regular 'external' storage.

Comment: Thanks for hint. Do you have any idea on how can we (Or is it possible), that we can copy multiple image files to Shared collections Downloads ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941836/how-to-perform-multiple-files-copy-to-shared-collections-downloads-for-android Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean in the last point about "open the URI as a stream and write it to a real file somewhere you control." Does this mean that I need to create the Sqlite file in scoped storage and then copy the file to the user-selected location?

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files), the files located in your external storage will be removed upon uninstallation of your application. Hence, you might consider using [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) function to store your files in the top level shared storage. If you want to store in the [DOWNLOADS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) directory, you can use the following to get the directory path.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment. DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not talking such. I'm talking on upcoming Android Q scoped storage.

Comment: I think I understood your problem. Keeping the files in the `MediaStore.Download` is the same as you store the file in the `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` using the `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` function in my opinion. Though the blog that you shared does not say much about it. Please let me know if I have got anything wrong again.