# How to perform multiple files copy to Shared collections Downloads, for Android Q, Scoped Storage?

Tags: android

For upcoming [Android Q Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage), I was wondering how can we perform Files copy from and to?

---

### Before Android Q

I have several image files, which are located at the following location

```
Application.instance().getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/a.png";
Application.instance().getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/b.png";
Application.instance().getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/c.png";
```

To ensure those files retained even the app is uninstalled, the app will copy image files to the following location

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/com.yocto.wenote/backup/a.png";
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/com.yocto.wenote/backup/b.png";
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/com.yocto.wenote/backup/c.png";
```

A simple `java.io.File` copy operation will able to accomplish this.

```
public static boolean copy(File src, File dst) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(src);
        out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    } finally {
        close(out);
        close(in);
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

### For Android Q, Scoped Storage

`java.io.File` is no longer usable under Android Q, Scoped Storage.

According to https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage

> If your app creates files that belong to the user, and that the user
>   expects to be retained when your app is uninstalled, then save them
>   into one of the common media collections, also known as shared
>   collections. Shared collections include: Photos & Videos, Music, and
>   Downloads.

We would like to have the 3 image files copy to Shared collections **Downloads**. But, we can hardly get a concrete code example, on how to achieve so?

---

How can we perform multiple files copy to Shared collections Downloads, for Android Q, Scoped Storage?

Answer (score 2):

Call `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs()`

Now you can read and write to a sandboxed view of the downloads folder restricted to your app's files only, using standard `File` APIs. If you open the default files app and navigate to downloads, you'll see all downloads from all apps including yours. (on the emulator at least)

Comment: This is great, can this same level of access be achieved on external sd card's Download directory?